# change coding md5 vb.net into php

Tags: php, vb.net

I have code BV.net like these

```
Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
Dim des As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

des.Key = MD5Hash(key)
des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB

Dim buffer As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
Return Convert.ToBase64String(des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
```

My problem is, i wanna make php md5 but when i try compare is not matching.

Like these

```
echo md5('111');
```

result on php `698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668`
but on vb.net result is `M+wq3Qt9bfg=.` 
So i dont have any idea how to make my md5 on php get value like on vb.net. Any idea about these??

NOTE : the code vb.net not mine build but is my friend build it.

Comment: md5 is no good for hashing of passwords as it's now way too weak. PHP has functions for dealing with the hashing of passwords http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: Your VB.NET code doesn't MD5 hash the value, it encrypts it using DES encryption. If you want to create an MD5 hash I suggest you google _"VB.NET MD5 Hash"_.  Be aware though that both MD5 and DES are very weak hashing/encryption algorithms these days and very easy to break/exploit.

Comment: Well on my question is meaning i need translate that vb.net coce into php code. Cause on vb.net i saw md5 so prob i'm using md5 too on php. But all you said vb.net not create md5, soo my sugettion i need to cahnge or hash something. But i dont have any idea how to make hash like vb.net

Answer (score 0):

I dont think I fully understand this, but,`Return Convert.ToBase64String(des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))` Return a symmetric encryptor object converted to Base64 string.

While your php code`echo md5('111');` returns md5 sum in hex format. You can convert the md5 output to base64 but I dont think it will work as the output from VB.net is that of an encryptor object not MD5sum

Comment: [**`TransformFinalBlock()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the encrypted data, not an "encryptor object". [**`Convert.ToBase64String()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) only accepts byte arrays, so if the former would return anything other than that the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: So you mean i need to convert something into base64?? Well i try that but is kinda still not same relsult as on vb.net. Or i need to change convert into ascii??